# Creating an initialization list of abstract base type references

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have two classes A,B which inherit from an abstract base class Abs. I would like to create an initialization list containing both of them. I would like to iterate on that list with a foreach loop.

```
class Abs {
    public:
    virtual ~Abs() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class A : public Abs {
    virtual void f() override;
};

class B : public Abs {
    virtual void f();
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    const Abs& a_abs = a;
    const Abs& b_abs = b;

    for (const auto& abs : {a_abs, b_abs})
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation of the for loop fails with:

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Abs’

Why is it trying to allocate an Abs type?

How can I overcome that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were a few things wrong with your code:

- you should have a public destructor/constructor
- B doesn't inherit from Abs therefore in can't be converted to Abs

i don't know if you can get what you want with references but with pointers you can. please use smart pointer this is just a prof of concept

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class Abs {
    public:
    virtual ~Abs() = default;
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

class A : public Abs {
    public:
    virtual void f() const {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public Abs {
    public:
    virtual void f() const {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    const Abs* a_abs = dynamic_cast<const Abs *>(a);
    const Abs* b_abs = dynamic_cast<const Abs *>(b);

    for (const auto* abs : {a_abs, b_abs})
    {
        abs->f();
    }
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are correct about the first two bullets. It appears I was a bit careless when I wrote the example :-/  , but why do I need to dynamic_cast? It seems to compile and work without it

Comment: it isn't required but it make sure that no other conversion then the one you what happens
but you are right i shouldn't have put it in things wrong but more as an advice